# Python TableOne passes unexpected argument to pandas.concat()

Tags: python, pandas

Get error with with a Python module. Seems like it tries to pass an argument to Pandas `concat`. I use Linux and Anaconda.

```
import pandas as pd
from tableone import TableOne

d = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['1', '2', '3']})
TableOne(d, ['a', 'b'], categorical=['b'])

table = pd.concat([self.cont_table,self.cat_table],sort=False)
```

```
TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'
```

```
tableone.__version__
Out[27]: '0.5.13'
pd.__version__
Out[28]: '0.22.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat in Pandas version 0.22.0 doesn't have sort as a argument. This can be found in the documentation for Pandas 0.22.0 concat (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.concat.html)

If you upgrade to pandas 0.23.4 sort is included as an argument (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html
).

Comment: thanks for picking this up. i have updated the package, so new tableone installations should prompt to upgrade pandas if necessary.